# Trying to figure out activeweb logging to a separate file

Tags: activeweb

I am trying to use the default active web library to log everything to a separate log file. Right now I'm running everything under IntelliJ (via mvn jetty:run) and all the logging is coming out to the console only.

I tried added a log4j.properties file in the WEB-INF directory; didn't work (I have not added log4j dependency to my pom as I don't want it in there).

Looking a slf4j, I cannot find any properties or config file that let's me define how I would log to a specific log file. And, I'm not sure what logging AW uses, so it's hard to see what I need to configure.

Stuck at this point, and just googling and reading thru the slf4j site to try to get this working.

Comment: you write: "separate file" - separate from what?

Comment: I would like to redirect logging to a ${project.basedir}/logs/log.txt file. Currently I am doing this by telling IntelliJ to send all console logging to this file. But, I would like to configure it somewhere. In log4j, I could create all my loggers and rolling file configs as I pleased. This is useful for me logging certain parts of code base to separate files. I am looking to separate default AW logging from my code as well as break out logging by package name if I want.

Comment: yep, see my answer, I believe it has everything you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I general, if you want logging done by Log4j and Slf4j, you will need to add appropriate dependencies. Here is the configuration from one of our projects:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

this will bring appropriate deps.

Here is the contents of the `log4j.properties` file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, ${logger-name}, SPLUNK

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.SPLUNK=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SPLUNK.File=${catalina.home}/logs/worker-splunk.log
log4j.appender.SPLUNK.Append=true
log4j.appender.SPLUNK.Encoding=UTF-8

# This is a filter that will filter out junk we do not want to sent to Splunk
log4j.appender.SPLUNK.filter.1=app.utils.SplunkLogFilter
log4j.appender.SPLUNK.layout=org.javalite.logging.JsonLog4jLayout


log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${catalina.home}/logs/worker.log
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.javalite.logging.JsonLog4jLayout
```

The `logger-name` is a Maven- filtered property. Locally it is resolved to `CONSOLE` and when the app is built, it resolves to `FILE`. This way, we can observe log on the console during development.

The class `SplunkLogFilter` looks like this:

```
import org.apache.log4j.spi.Filter;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

public class SplunkLogFilter extends Filter {

    private static final String[] EXCLUDED_LOGGERS = new String[]{"***ServiceImpl", "app.utils.ProcessUtil"};
    private static final String[] EXCLUDED_MESSAGES = new String[]{"****Command"};

    @Override
    public int decide(LoggingEvent event) {
        String loggerName = event.getLoggerName();
        for (String excludedLogger : EXCLUDED_LOGGERS) {
            if(loggerName.equals(excludedLogger)){
                return Filter.DENY;
            }
        }
        String message = event.getMessage().toString();
        for (String excludedMessage : EXCLUDED_MESSAGES) {
            if(message.contains(excludedMessage)){
                return Filter.DENY;
            }
        }
        return Filter.NEUTRAL;
    }
}
```

So, we are logging into two files in parallel, where one is shipped into Splunk. 
The Splunk file is smaller, so we pay less for Splunk, but we retain full files just in case.

Comment: Makes total sense and what I've done on other projects. Sorry for not being clearer - I was hoping to not introduce another dependency. My current pom has this dep in there:

`<dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.4</version>
 </dependency>`

So, what I am trying to do is use slf4j itself and configure it vs. adding in log4j deps and then configuring that. Thank you for your answer(s); I'm just trying to see what I can and cannot do with stock AW.

Comment: Understand, AW has a pluggable architecture for logging, it is up to you what to plug into it.

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work for me. I have the logging filter setup, as well as the appender. I have output to the file, but nothing from my specific package.
In my controllers I am using the `logDebug()` method and I do not see the log messages anywhere. I've made sure in my `EXCLUDED_LOGGERS` string that I do not have any of my packages or classes in it.
I'm also using Jetty and not tomcat - not that that should make a diff. I guess I'll keep plugging away, but I've already spent a few hours this morning and do not have the results I am looking for..

Comment: Oh, also, I have set the `rootLogger` to `DEBUG`, so I should not have an issue with `logDebug()`. In fact, I see all kinds of activemq (I'm using async) and `TemplateLoader` debug messages. So, I know it's working, somewhat.

Comment: I ended up just using log4j2 outside of AW logging. All working as expected.

Comment: We do not have such issues. Make sure your log4j.properties sets the right log level.